How to make the series text responsive in highcharts?
I am using highcharts. Everything seems fine but I am not sure how to make the series text (LLLL! LLLL! LLLL!, XYZM XYZM XYZM XYZM) responsive/ wrap text depending upon the screen size? Right now, if I minimize the screen, the text overlaps on each other. Is there a way to make the text wrap instead of overlapping? Here is my code.


// container7
var chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true,
    height: 200


  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    lineColor: 'white',
    categories: ['ABCD'],
    labels: {
      padding: 40, // Add padding of 40 to the x-axis labels
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px' // Adjust the font size as needed
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    max: 100,
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: false // Hide y-axis labels
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0 // Remove grid lines
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal', // this will be our default
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          color: 'black', // Set font color to black
          fontSize: '13px', // Set font size to 12px
          textShadow: 'none' // Remove text shadow
        },
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', // Set background color to transparent
        formatter: function() {
          return this.series.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  },


  colors: ['#d37295', '#fabfd2'],
  series: [{
    name: 'LLLL!LLLL!LLLL!LLLL!LLLL!LLLL!LLLL!',
    data: [57]
  }, {
    name: 'XYZM XYZMXYZMXYZMXYZM XYZMXYZM XYZM XYZM',
    data: [43]
  }],
  legend: {
    enabled: false // Hide the legend
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false // Hide the credits
  }
};

// Render the chart using Highcharts
Highcharts.chart('container7', chartOptions);
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<h2>... look like this:</h2>
<div id="container7" style=" border: 1px solid lightgray;"></div>




You can use responsive mechanism and textOverflow option to wrap the labels on smaller resolutions.
Docs:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.style
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fejb90zy/
responsive: {
rules: [{
  condition: {
    maxWidth: 850
  },
  chartOptions: {
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        dataLabels: {
          style: {
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
            width: 50
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
}


I was trying to avoid ellipsis and instead wrap the text. I ended up adding a javscript for this instead of adding ellipsis.

Adding javascript? You can just change the textOverflow value to clip for example. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jn8t6u5h/
